# Dismissing/Updating Local Notification Programmatically in iPhone sdk4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, notifications, local, ios4

I am working on an app that runs in the background with the backgroundmode set to location. In the didUpdateToLocation: method, I want to generate local notification. I want the app to show the notification only when previous notification has been viewed. Another option is to show only the latest notification and dismiss all the previous notifications programmatically (i.e. without user interaction). Please guide me how is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    // Clear out the old notification before scheduling a new one.
    if ([oldNotifications count] > 0) {
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
```